# What other suttas instruct how to do Anapanasati, apart from the Anapanasati Sutta?

Tags: reference-request, meditation-breath, anapanasati

Anapanasati is mainly covered in the Anapanasati Sutta.

Some of these instructions (perhaps additional instructions) are also written elsewhere: for example in the Anapana Samuthiya, Girimananda Sutta, the Sattipattana Suttas, Kayagatasati Sutta, etc.

What are the additional instructions or variations covered elsewhere, not covered in the Anapanasati Sutta?

I hope that answers will do one or more of the following:

- Reference suttas (apart from the Anapanasati Sutta) which include Anapanasati instructions
- Quote the instructions, examples or guidance which are different or which are additional to that given in the Anapanasati Sutta
- If it already given in the Anapanasati Sutta without variation, no need to quote or mention.
- Comparison with Sanskrit and Tibetan text is also welcome.

Comment: [Here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/128908692/Mindfulness-of-Breathing-in-the-Samyukta-Agama) is an article by [*Anālayo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu_Analayo) which you might find useful. It discusses the differences between *Ānāpāna* texts in the *Nikāyas* & *Āgamas*.

Comment: Thanks will check this out. But is it possible to give an answer also for the record. Will be useful for someone else.

Comment: I didn't put it in the answer box because the article is not a comparison between texts *within* the *Pāḷi* Canon as the question requests. It's between *Pāḷi* and *Āgama* texts.  Anyway, when I have time to pull all the strings together, I'll try and give an appropriate answer with that article included. In the mean time, the article is still here in the comment section for everyone who's interested.

Comment: Edited it so you can use some of the material from the book also

Comment: Another [question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/if-you-consolidate-the-satipatthana-instruction-from-the-tripitaka-what-would-th) for you when you tackle the above as additional effort may not be needed

Comment: @Unrul3r wondering if you can attempt this questions. Eager to see what your answer would be.

Answer (score 4):

MN62 Maha-Rahulovada Sutta is one of them.

> "[1] Breathing in long, he discerns, 'I am breathing in long'; or
>   breathing out long, he discerns, 'I am breathing out long.' [2] Or
>   breathing in short, he discerns, 'I am breathing in short'; or
>   breathing out short, he discerns, 'I am breathing out short.' [3] He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe in sensitive to the entire body.' He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe out sensitive to the entire body.' [4]
>   He trains himself, 'I will breathe in calming bodily fabrication.' He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe out calming bodily fabrication.'
>
> "[5] He trains himself, 'I will breathe in sensitive to rapture.' He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe out sensitive to rapture.' [6] He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe in sensitive to pleasure.' He trains
>   himself, 'I will breathe out sensitive to pleasure.' [7] He trains
>   himself, 'I will breathe in sensitive to mental fabrication.' He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe out sensitive to mental fabrication.'
>   [8] He trains himself, 'I will breathe in calming mental fabrication.'
>   He trains himself, 'I will breathe out calming mental fabrication.'
>
> "[9] He trains himself, 'I will breathe in sensitive to the mind.' He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe out sensitive to the mind.' [10] He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe in satisfying the mind.' He trains
>   himself, 'I will breathe out satisfying the mind.' [11] He trains
>   himself, 'I will breathe in steadying the mind.' He trains himself, 'I
>   will breathe out steadying the mind.' [12] He trains himself, 'I will
>   breathe in releasing the mind.' He trains himself, 'I will breathe out
>   releasing the mind.'
>
> "[13] He trains himself, 'I will breathe in focusing on inconstancy.'
>   He trains himself, 'I will breathe out focusing on inconstancy.' [14]
>   He trains himself, 'I will breathe in focusing on dispassion.'[5] He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe out focusing on dispassion.' [15] He
>   trains himself, 'I will breathe in focusing on cessation.' He trains
>   himself, 'I will breathe out focusing on cessation.' [16] He trains
>   himself, 'I will breathe in focusing on relinquishment.' He trains
>   himself, 'I will breathe out focusing on relinquishment.'
>
> "This, Rahula, is how mindfulness of in-&-out breathing is developed &
>   pursued so as to be of great fruit, of great benefit.
>
> "When mindfulness of in-&-out breathing is developed & pursued in this
>   way, even one's final in-breaths & out-breaths are known as they
>   cease, not unknown."[6]

Just as the what was instructed by Buddha to Ven Rahula. This is the only way that i understand and experienced it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The Anapanasati Sutta is the only sutta that provides proper instruction in accordance to the Buddha-Dhamma, as follows.

> *Here, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu develops the mindfulness enlightenment factor, which is supported by seclusion, dispassion and cessation
>   and ripens in **relinquishment (vossagga)**. He develops the investigation-of-states
>   enlightenment factor…the energy enlightenment factor…the rapture
>   enlightenment factor…the tranquillity enlightenment factor…the
>   concentration enlightenment factor…the equanimity enlightenment
>   factor, which is supported by seclusion, dispassion and cessation
>   and ripens in **relinquishment (vossagga)**.*