# If you Consolidate the Satipatthana Instruction from the Tripitaka what would the additions and variation in Comparison to Maha Satipatthana Sutta

Tags: vipassana, satipatthana, meditation-mindfulness

If you consolidate the instructions from the Tripitaka and other sources what would be the variations and additions to the instructions given in the Maha Satipatthana Sutta?

Comment: The question in your text is different from the one in the title. What exactly do you want to compare? Satipatthana with Maha-Satipatthana? Or just Maha-Satipatthana with other sources?

Comment: If you compare Maha Sattipattana Sutta to the whole Tripitaka is it comprehensive or are there additional information or variations elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four comparison tables that expose the similarities and discrepancies in  *satipaṭṭhāna* discourses from the *Pāḷi Nikāyas* and Chinese *Āgamas*:
<sub>From *Mindfulness in Early Buddhism* by Tse-Fu Kuan, [p.166-169](https://ahandfulofleaves.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/mindfulness-in-early-buddhism_kuan.pdf#page=185). Click the images to enlarge.</sub>
[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: Is this a freely available book? Where can I get the whole thing? Also looking for a comparison within the Tripitaka also.

Comment: The whole book is available in the link I gave above or, alternatively, [here](http://ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/Mindfulness-in-Early-Buddhism_Kuan.pdf). In addition, you can find most of what you are looking for in [*A History of Mindfulness*](http://santifm.org/santipada/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/A_History_of_Mindfulness_Bhikkhu_Sujato.pdf) by *Sujato Bhikkhu*.